# Why cant the array be allocated successfully?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int find_cross(char*, int, int, int);
void reduction(char*, char*, int, int);

int main(){
    int n;
    int m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    char *data = new char[n * m];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> (data+i*m);
    }
    cout << "pass one" << endl;
    char *original = new char[n * m];
    cout << "pass two" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < n * m; i++){
        *(original+i) = *(data+i);
    }
    int biggest_size;
    if(n >= m){
        if(m % 2 == 0){
            biggest_size = m - 1;
        }else{
            biggest_size = m;
        }
    }else{
        if(n % 2 == 0){
            biggest_size = n - 1;
        }else{
            biggest_size = n;
        }
    }
    {
        int biggest = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < biggest_size + 1; i = i + 2){
            reduction(data, original, n, m);
            if(find_cross(data, i, n, m)){
                for(int j = biggest_size; j >= 1; j = j - 2){
                    if(find_cross(data, j, n, m)){
                        if((i * 2 - 1) * (j * 2 - 1) > biggest){
                            biggest = (i * 2 - 1) * (j * 2 - 1);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        cout << biggest;
    }
    delete [] data;
    delete [] original;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int find_cross(char* data, int size, int row, int column){
    for(int i = (size - 1) / 2; i < row - (size - 1) / 2; i++){
        for(int j = (size - 1) / 2; j < column - (size - 1) / 2; j++){
            int yes = 1;
            for(int k = 0; k < (size - 1) / 2 + 1; k++){
                if(*(data+(i+k)*column+j) != 'G' || *(data+(i-k)*column+j) != 'G' || *(data+i*column+j+k) != 'G' || *(data+i*column+j-k) != 'G'){
                    yes = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(yes == 1){
                for(int k = 0; k < (size - 1) / 2 + 1; k++){
                    *(data+(i-k)*column+j) = 'A';
                    *(data+(i+k)*column+j) = 'A';
                    *(data+i*column+j+k) = 'A';
                    *(data+i*column+j-k) = 'A';
                }
                return 1;
            }else if(i == row - (size - 1) / 2 - 1 && j == column - (size - 1) / 2 - 1){
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

void reduction(char* data, char* original, int row, int column){
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < column; j++){
            *(data+i*column+j) = *(original+i*column+j);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my input:

```
14 12
GGGGGGGGGGGG
GGGGGGGGGGGG
BGBGGGBGBGBG
BGBGGGBGBGBG
GGGGGGGGGGGG
GGGGGGGGGGGG
GGGGGGGGGGGG
GGGGGGGGGGGG
BGBGGGBGBGBG
BGBGGGBGBGBG
BGBGGGBGBGBG
BGBGGGBGBGBG
GGGGGGGGGGGG
GGGGGGGGGGGG
```

Execution result:

```
14 12
GGGGGGGGGGGG
GGGGGGGGGGGG
BGBGGGBGBGBG
BGBGGGBGBGBG
GGGGGGGGGGGG
GGGGGGGGGGGG
GGGGGGGGGGGG
GGGGGGGGGGGG
BGBGGGBGBGBG
BGBGGGBGBGBG
BGBGGGBGBGBG
BGBGGGBGBGBG
GGGGGGGGGGGG
GGGGGGGGGGGG
pass one

--------------------------------
Process exited after 256.8 seconds with return value 3221226356
```

The problem is occurred at `char *original = new char[n * m];`, it cant execute successfully, and the program is crash. But there is a strange things happen, the array `char *data = new char[n * m];` can be allocated successfully. What happened, and how to solved this problem?
[Original picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1APzy.png)

Comment: I haven't checked your code carefully but most likely you access out of bounds of the array. Try using `vector` instead of `new char`, and `at(x)` instead of `[x]`. And catch exceptions

Comment: I dont know why it is crush. and return is not a 0.

Comment: What "problem ... occurred"?  How can we know "what happened" if you don't explain it clearly?

Comment: You're writing past the end of `data`, which is undefined.

Comment: The pointer arithmetic is far too complex for anyone to be able to say "this is indeed correct". Write an index calculation function and use it.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forgetting about the nul terminator which is added when reading strings. Your second allocation fails because you have corrupted the heap by writing out of bounds. You need one more byte in your array

```
char *data = new char[n * m + 1];
```

Or you could do the sensible thing and recognise this as a lesson learned and use a vector of strings.

```
vector<string> data(n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cin >> data[i];
}
vector<string> original = data;
```

See how much clearer and easier your code becomes?

Comment: Could you please tell me why the program crushed after `cout << "pass one";`, Im so comfused.

Comment: Because you wrote beyond the bounds of your array,

Comment: @WhozCraig I counted 12

Comment: @WhozCraig The OP is not interested in nul terminators. Each nul terminator gets overwritten by the next read. Excapt the last of course, that is the one that is the problem

Comment: @john Now I just did too. Thanks for making me check for a third time =P. That size allocation should be `n * (m+1)`, btw, if each string is terminated, otherwise, you're spot on. Thanks for keeping me honest.

Comment: @WhozCraig I don't think so because I don't think the OP is interested in nul terminators. This is a matrix not a vector of strings.

Comment: @john I suspect you're correct to that. Man, I really need to get new glasses, I checked that first input row *twice* and came to 11 both times. Maybe I need to up the point size of my monitor. Getting old *sucks*.

Comment: Could you please tell me why the program crushed after `cout << "pass one" << endl;` Im so confused.

Comment: @000 As I keep saying you wrote beyond the bounds of your array. What is it you don't understand about that? Where's the confusion?

Comment: @000 When you read 12 characters from your input, you write **thirteen** characters to your array. That's why your array is not big enough. The extra character is the nul terminator.

Comment: @000 Because you write beyond your array limits, and in so doing invoke **undefined behavior**. At that point, anything can happen, and if you're *fortunate* that anything will be a crash. At least then you know something is wrong. It is far, far worse when it seems to work for you (UB can do that too), but when submitted to a professor (or worse, a *customer*), only in *those* environments does it crash, and you're left wondering what went wrong (kind of like now).

Comment: No wander that program can pass some test case without crash

Comment: @000: UB doesn't guarantee a crash